# Create a trigger that validates the data for the Product object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have an apex trigger (before insert/update) and a helper class to that trigger. The *problem* is: When creating an object record, the trigger should check if the AddedDate field is filled and if it's not - then assign it today's date and current time.

And when I create and update a Product object record, the trigger must check the length of the Description field, if the field is longer than 200 characters, I must trim it to 197 characters and add a triple to the end of the line.
What am I doing wrong and how should I proceed?

**My trigger**:

```
trigger ProductTrigger on Product__c (before insert, before update) { 
       if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        ProductTriggerHelper.producthandler(Trigger.new);
    }


}
```

**Trigger helper class**:

```
public class ProductTriggerHelper {

    public static void producthandler(List<Product__c> products) {
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Product__c.Description__c.getDescribe(); 
        Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();

        //List<Product__c> prList = new list<Product__c>(); 
        for(Product__c pr: products){

            pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();

            if (String.isNotEmpty(pr.Description__c)) {
               pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(lengthOfField);
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirements

> When creating an object record, the trigger should check if the AddedDate field is filled and if it's not - then assign it today's date and current time.

You aren't doing that.

Change `pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();` to

`if (pr.AddedDate__c == null) { pr.AddedDate__c=system.today(); }`

Also according to the [abbreviate function documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_abbreviate) the parameter it takes is the max length including the 3 elipses.

So change `pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(lengthOfField);` to

`pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(200);`

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Programmatic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135974/programmatic)'s answer...

You defined the trigger as `before insert, before update`. Cool, that's perfect place for doing data validations, field prepopulation... And you'll get save to database for free!

But then this clashes with next line `if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){`. With this setup it'll never fire. Either remove the if completely or (if you think trigger can get more events in future) go with `trigger.isBefore && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)`.

P.S. It's datetime field? So `pr.AddedDate__c=system.now();` is better